# Share data from one database to two different db

Tags: mysql

For example I have:

```
database_root (with "table1_test"..)
```

and then I have (but those tables doesn't have "table1_test")

```
db_1
db_2
```

I want to share the data of database_root to db_1 and 2, and if someone is looking for data on table1_test on db_1 or 2... automatically the data is collected from database_root.

I don't really know if it's complicated, because I don't know so much of MySQL so... tell me if it's possible (if it's possible please tell me how to) or no.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.this, b.that
     FROM database_root AS a
     JOIN db_1 AS b  ON a.x = b.x;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is in response to the OP's question. He is initially talking about having to query data from multiple databases `database_root`, `db_1` and `db_2` from the table `table1_test`.

Comment: yeah, i know that but i want to make it automaticly... ex: `SELECT * FROM table1_test` on db_1 for example... (remember that table is only on "database_root") ty!